# Преобразовать номера телефонов к единому формату (из одних цифр)

Tags: sql-server

В базе хранятся номера телефонов в виде +7 (999) 999 99 99 , но возможны и другие разделители. Необходимо получить просто набор цифр. Понятно что можно использовать множество вложенных в друг друга Replace , но возможно есть более красивое решение 
(база ms sql 2008)

Comment: проще всего 30 штук case when налепить.. Но... возможно через xml можно более простое решение сочинить...

Comment: regex - c 2012 сервера https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206404/mssql-regular-expression

Comment: @nick_n_a дак речь про 2008, да и регулярки там для фильтрации используются, а тут нужно из поля выбрать все `\d`, т.е. фактически удалить все `[^\d]` из значений

Comment: ой какой костыль получится =)

Comment: Какое красивое решение вы ожидаете? Цикл в хранимке? (не все системы любят хранимки). Цикл вне хранимки - это юнионы и групировка - будет громоздко. С xml хорошего результата не будет.

Comment: А встроеной функции - нету.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой и надёжный способ

```
select 
case when substring( phone+'                    ',1,1) between '0' and '9' then substring( phone+'                    ',1,1) else '' end +
case when substring( phone+'                    ',2,1) between '0' and '9' then substring( phone+'                    ',2,1) else '' end +
case when substring( phone+'                    ',3,1) between '0'and'9' then substring( phone+'                    ',3,1) else '' end +
--// и так далее
case when substring( phone+'                    ',20,1) between '0'and'9'  then substring( phone+'                    ',20,1) else '' end 
from (select '+7 (999) 999 99 9' as phone ) t
```

Цикл я показал от 1 до 20, и пробелов сзади добавить по 20.
Пробелы можно не добавлять, если поле `char(20)` - потому что такое поле само дополняется пробелами. Т.е.  `phone+'                    '` еквивалентно `cast(phone as char(20))`, но если поле изначально `char(20)` то ничего делать не нужно. Так же можно каст вынести за скобки, т.е.

```
select 
case when substring( phone,1,1)) between'0'and'9'then substring(phone,1,1) else '' end +
case when substring( phone,2,1) between'0'and'9'then substring(phone,2,1) else '' end +
--....
from ( select cast (phone as char(20)) phone from table1 ) t
```

Есть ещё вариант - написать хранимую ф-цию... и запхать туда цикл... но думаю так будет само проще.

А самый простой вариант - реплейсить

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(phone, '+',''),'-',''),'(',''),')','')  from table1
```

Но... менее надёжный. А если запретов более 20 - то через чур громоздкий.

Можно ещё хранимку задействовать

```
  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPhone] (
    @@s VarChar(max)
  ) RETURNS VarChar(max) AS BEGIN
       DECLARE  @Result VarChar(max)
       declare @i int
       set @Result = ''
       set @i = 1
       while @i <= len(@@s)  begin
         if (SUBSTRING(@@s,@i,1) between '0' and '9') 
           set @Result = @Result + SUBSTRING(@@s,@i,1)
         set @i = @i + 1
       end
       RETURN @Result 
       end
```